# How to solve 3 linear equations in three variables using cross multiplication method?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

How to solve 3 linear  equations in 3 variables using cross multiplication method?  I have no problem in solving these equations using substituting. However, how do I solve these using cross multiplication?  I can solve two equations with 3 variables but have no idea if I just one more equation. One way- I believe - is to solve two equations at a time but is there any better way?

By cross multiplication, I mean [this](https://www.math-only-math.com/cross-multiplication-method.html).

Comment: You should edit your post to make clear what you mean by "cross multiplication method." It may be non-standard terminology.

Comment: @CameronBuie I edited the question.

Comment: I think you might be after Cramer's Rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule. The Wikipedia Page offers some formulae for 2 and 3 dimensions. The $3\times 3$ grids of numbers are called determinants: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

Answer (score 2):

A system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns $x,y,z$ can be written as

$$x\vec{U}+y\vec{V}+z\vec{W}=\vec{R}\tag{1}$$

with $\vec{U},\vec{V},\vec{W},\vec{R} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ (think to column vectors).

If you compute for example

$$\vec{V_1}:=\vec{V} \times \vec{W}, $$
it suffices to take the dot product of (1) with $\vec{V_1}$ to obtain

$$x\vec{U}.\vec{V_1}+y\underbrace{\vec{V}.\vec{V_1}}_{= 0}+z\underbrace{\vec{W}.\vec{V_1}}_{= 0}=\vec{R}.\vec{V_1}\tag{2}$$

whence :

> $$x=\dfrac{\vec{R}.\vec{V_1}}{\vec{U}.\vec{V_1}} 
> \ \  \text{with} \ \ \vec{V_1}:=\vec{V} \times \vec{W}\tag{3}$$

It remains to do the same thing for unknowns $y$ and $z$.

Remark : In fact (3) is a quotient of 2 [triple products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) ; thus we find back a way of establishing/writing Cramer's formulas as remarked by @ryan221b.